# Alert Disappearing for an outside touch

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using alert component in my application.
Its working fine in ios but in android when alert appears and when I click on outside the alert is diappearing.
Here is my code:

```
Alert.alert('XXXx', 'Password must contain 8 characters', [{text: 'OK'}]);
```

I tried this also:

Alert.alert('XXXx', 'Password must contain 8 characters', [{text: 'OK'}], { cancelable: false});

My react-native version : "0.25.1"

Comment: According to the source (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Alert/Alert.js), `{cancelable: false}` should be a valid option. However I don't know enough about Android bridge how it really affects on the outside click. But there doesn't seem to be other options but to hook showing alert in `while` loop where button press returns a value that exits the loop.

Comment: I have written like this:  while(this.state.alert){
             Alert.alert('Roger', 'Please enter email', [{text: 'OK',onPress:()=>{
              this.setState({alert:false})}}]);
           }but the alert is not displaying.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  Alert.alert(
    "XXXx",
    "Password must contain 8 characters",
    [
      {
        text: "OK",
        onPress: () => {},
      },
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
  );
}, 500);
```